# DuckDB performance on NFS storage

Tags: duckdb

I am really interested about duckdb and i would like to migrate from SQLite to DuckDB.
But for some reasons, i need to put my databases on NFS (As noticed in the SQlite documentation, It's a really bad idea to put SQLite on NFS and that is why we have some performance issues because of NFS Locks)

That being said, I was wondering if i will have the same issues with DuckDB on NFS or if DuckDB will be more efficient than SQLite on NFS ?

Can't find any documentation about that.

(again, i know it's a really bad idea to store SQLite database on NFS, but for some reason i have no choice to do that... but, this is another topic)

Thank you guys.

Comment: This really depends on the workload. Is your workload write-heavy, does it have inserts/deletes or a mix of the two?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
In my use case, it's read only 95% of the time.
For the other 5%, it's writing and reading in the same time but with a single process.
But even with read only, i have a lot of performance issues with SQLite on NFS (the workaround is to lock the sqlite database. With this locking mode enabled, i have better performance)
Maybe DuckDB would be better for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DuckDB is a good fit for running over the network, including using NFS.

DuckDB [stores the data in a compressed form and uses relatively large (256 kB) blocks](https://duckdb.org/2022/10/28/lightweight-compression.html). These help reduce the number of file system requests and locks required. Thanks to this, DuckDB also works well [over HTTP(S) and on the AWS S3 object storage](https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Great to hear that !